# how to get id of unique column

Tags: php, mysql

1. insert article and find the tags in it
2. insert one tag and one reference one by one to know the last_insert_id() of tag

---

```
$tags = array('strawberries','blueberries','food','strawberries')

function hashTagInsert($tags) 
    {
        /// commit this as a transaction

        $lastInsertId = $this->db->lastId(); // last insert id of article

        foreach ($tags as $val)
        {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO tags (tag, added) VALUES (:tag, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurrence = occurrence + 1';
            $this->db->boolQuery($sql, array(':tag' => $val));

            $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO tags_refs (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (:lastInsertId, LAST_INSERT_ID())';
            $this->db->boolQuery($sql2, array(':lastInsertId' => $lastInsertId));
        }
    }
```

I wrote script like that to take care of it. and it works. Unfortunately there is a bit problem with duplicities because there is a unique column.

If there is duplicity there is the origin tag as it was and I don't know that id it has. In another table after that I have got new reference for last insert tag which doesn't exist.

The tag exists but the reference is wrong.

The DB looks like that after the first processing script:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `occurrence` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `tag`, `occurrence`, `added`) VALUES
(18,    'boobs',    1,  '2015-05-29 16:46:44'),
(20,    'food', 0,  '2015-05-29 16:46:44'),
(19,    'blueberries',  0,  '2015-05-29 16:46:44');

and the reference one:

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tags_refs`;
CREATE TABLE `tags_refs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tags_refs` (`id`, `article_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(24,    31, 18),
(25,    31, 19),
(26,    31, 20),
(27,    31, 26);

-- 2015-05-29 14:49:55
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! A formatting tip - rather than using `<pre>` tags, highlight your code and use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k`, which will indent it 4 spaces as a code block and apply syntax highlighting based on the assigned tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hashTagInsert($tags) 
{
    /// commit this as a transaction

    $lastInsertId = $this->db->lastId();

    foreach ($tags as $val)
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tags (tag, added) VALUES (:tag, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurrence = occurrence + 1, last_article_id = :lastInsertId';
        $stmt = $this->db->boolQuery($sql, array(':tag' => $val,
                                                 ':lastInsertId' => $lastInsertId));

        if(!$stmt)
        {
           $sql3 = 'SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = :tag';

           $existingTagId = $this->db->queryFetch($sql3, array(':tag' => $val));
        }

        $tagId = (isset($existingTagId)? $existingTagId : $this->db->lastId());

        $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO tags_refs (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (:lastInsertId, :tagId)';
        $this->db->boolQuery($sql2, array(':lastInsertId' => $lastInsertId,
                                          ':tagId' => $tagId));

        unset($existingTagId);
    }
}
```